No Gulp Found Error - in sharepoint package deployment
I'm trying to Embed Microsoft Team in Sharepoint and following this article step by step Website
I'm getting the error gulp package-solution --ship
No GulpFile found
No GulpFile found
I'm in the last step to deploy to sharepoint
Appreciate a help
Waiting to hear from you.
Mary

You need to run commands in the solution folder, not in the C:\Windows\System32

you mean node js folder?

I mean the folder where your project is. in the linked article, it is something like sp-dev-fx-webparts/samples/react-script-editor. You need the cd command at the step 3, unless you already are in the project directory (which is assumed by this sample).

Yes. It works. Thank you.

Step 3. Package and Deploy the Script Editor Web Part
Once you have the Script Editor web part installed and working locally, package it so that it can be deployed to your SharePoint app catalog:
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
Upload the generated .sppkg file (usually found in the sharepoint/solution/ folder) to your SharePoint app catalog. This will allow you to add the Script Editor web part to your SharePoint pages.

Upload the generated .sppkg file...
